# Detect added or deleted element from json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have created classes for Json deserializing but I want to get elements which is deleted or added in json and this is not in my classes. How can I do that I mean want to best way.

I am fetching user profile from Facebook and deserializing if facebook add or remove any element then how can i get this. I am using Json.net

let understand with example

**before**

example Json

```
{
       "Name":"Rahul",
       "isverified" : true
}
```

and I created c# class

```
public class Profile
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool isverified { get; set; }
}
```

**after**

example Json

```
{
       "Name":"Rahul",
       "isverified" : true,
       "emailid": "xyx@example.com"
}
```

so now I can detect that `emailid` is added to the json

Answer (score 0):

You want to receive callbacks from Facebook when properties are updated.  This doesn't relate to JSON, but Facebook offers a [realtime updates API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) which lets you subscribe to certain data to receive notifications when they are changed.  This is part of the Graph API.

Per the link, there are two steps required to set this up:

> 1. Set up an endpoint URL that receives both HTTP GET (for subscription verification) and POST (for actual change data) requests from Facebook.
> 2. Make a POST to the graph API url https://graph.facebook.com//subscriptions to subscribe, and be ready to handle the verification request.

You can subscribe to changes in properties relating to *users*, *permissions* (as in permissions users have granted to your application), and *pages* that have installed your application.

**Edit**

If you just want to be able to add properties at runtime, you could use an IDictionary, or an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

```
var Profile = new ExpandoObject();
Profile.Name = "Rahul";
Profile.emailid = "xyz@example.com";
Profile.foo = "bar";
```

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya I updated my answer.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: your code is not compiling I used this in console application -->   namespace MyTestProject
{
    using System.Dynamic;
    using System;
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var Profile = new ExpandoObject();
            Profile.Name = "Rahul";
            Profile.emailid = "xyz@example.com";
            Profile.foo = "bar";
            Console.Write(Profile.Name);
        }
    }
}

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya I'm not sure.  Can you check which Framework version you're using in project properties?  Make sure it's 4.0 and *not* the Client Profile.

Comment: I am using 4.0 exactly, I think you need to use dynamic.

Comment: anyway it is not solving my issue because i am using old classes and want to detect change in json against classes.

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya I'm not sure you've thought this through.  What kind of application is it (ASP.NET?).  Where is the JSON object defined (Javascript?  Your server-side code?).  What process updates the JSON (your Javascript? Facebook callbacks to your server? Or is this undecided?)

Comment: I tagged my question under C# then its clear its server side technology, and I am just showing example of facebook, my clear question is compare deserialize class against json, is any element extra or missed programaticaly using c# .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12923/discussion-between-dbaseman-and-govind-kamalaprakash-malviya)